# Jenkins - Node JS + GitHub integration fails on windows 10 during build

Tags: node.js, github, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to configure continues integration for node js using Jenkins version 1.6

**Step 1: 
I have configured NodeJS installations as below by keeping global configuration**

[image: Global Configuration]

**Step 2: My Job Configuration selection node global config here**

[image: Job Configuration]

**Step 3: My Job Console, it is fetching proper git repo while installing npm it fails**
[image: Job Console]

```
 > C:\Git\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Git\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f f1612bda9378e7f03738d142a5ce7c0d0a55f6c3
 > C:\Git\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list f1612bda9378e7f03738d142a5ce7c0d0a55f6c3 # timeout=10
Unpacking https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.9.0/node-v6.9.0-win-x86.zip to C:\Users\Selva\.jenkins\tools\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\node_v6.9 on Jenkins
[substack] $ C:\Users\Selva\.jenkins\tools\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\node_v6.9\node.exe C:\Users\Selva\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson640278178448032292.js
C:\Users\Selva\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson640278178448032292.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { npm install
                                                                  ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
Build step 'Execute NodeJS script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
    enter code here
```

If there is any mistake on which step i need to change,im using windows 10 machine with jenkins stable version

Here i have followed documentation of official jenkins wiki page.
[Node JS Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin)

Does anyone please help to resolve this Node JS + Github + Jenkins config

Comment: solution please

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On step 2, you shouldn't be running `npm install` as a step of type *Execute NodeJS script*.

- This expects you to enter valid Node Javascript as the *Script*, for example `console.log('I should be valid javascript code')`.

Leave **Provide Node and npm bin/ folder to PATH** marked and replace the **Execute NodeJS script** step with a **Windows PowerShell** script where you enter `npm install` as the **Script** value.

Comment: Obvious, but still I didn't understand what is the problem before reading the answer. Thanks! Same thing happened to me with Linux system and I was going mad.

Comment: I can feel your pain, waster a few hours myself!

Comment: I am trying to execute the shell command but it is not working ```/usr/local/bin/npm install```

Comment: I am helped by your comment. Thanks a lot, @Daniel J.G.